# PHP DOM envolver blockquote entre etiquetas iframe

Tags: php, dom

me podrian ayudar 
tengo este codigo html:

```
<div class="media_embed">
    <blockquote class="twitter-video" data-lang="es" height="" width="">
        <p dir="ltr" lang="es">"Mi cabeza está en REGRESAR a jugar y TRIUNFAR”<br />
        <br />
        ¡<a href="https://twitter.com/MartinZB85?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@MartinZB85</a> reconoce que le faltó madurez durante su paso por <a href="https://twitter.com/ClubAmerica?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@ClubAmerica</a>!<br />
        <br />
        | <a href="https://twitter.com/r_umanzor?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@r_umanzor</a><br />
        <br />
        | <a href="https://twitter.com/DANGAMEZ?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@DANGAMEZ</a> y <a href="https://twitter.com/ElDonLalonio?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@ElDonLalonio</a><br />
        <br />
        <a href="https://t.co/0aF1jxNOTB">https://t.co/0aF1jxNOTB</a> <a href="https://t.co/a7AnKbJURk">pic.twitter.com/a7AnKbJURk</a></p>
        — DIARIO RÉCORD (@record_mexico) <a href="https://twitter.com/record_mexico/status/954051794048569345?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">18 de enero de 2018</a>
    </blockquote>
    <script async="" charset="utf-8" height="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" width=""></script>
</div>
```

El cual tiene que tener esta salida:

```
<div class="media_embed">
    <figure class="op-interactive">
        <iframe>
            <blockquote class="twitter-video" data-lang="es" height="" width="">
                <p dir="ltr" lang="es">"Mi cabeza está en REGRESAR a jugar y TRIUNFAR”<br />
                <br />
                ¡<a href="https://twitter.com/MartinZB85?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@MartinZB85</a> reconoce que le faltó madurez durante su paso por <a href="https://twitter.com/ClubAmerica?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@ClubAmerica</a>!<br />
                <br />
                | <a href="https://twitter.com/r_umanzor?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@r_umanzor</a><br />
                <br />
                | <a href="https://twitter.com/DANGAMEZ?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@DANGAMEZ</a> y <a href="https://twitter.com/ElDonLalonio?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@ElDonLalonio</a><br />
                <br />
                <a href="https://t.co/0aF1jxNOTB">https://t.co/0aF1jxNOTB</a> <a href="https://t.co/a7AnKbJURk">pic.twitter.com/a7AnKbJURk</a></p>
                — DIARIO RÉCORD (@record_mexico) <a href="https://twitter.com/record_mexico/status/954051794048569345?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">18 de enero de 2018</a>
            </blockquote>
        </iframe>
    </figure>
    <script async="" charset="utf-8" height="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" width=""></script>
</div>
```

Tengo este codigo en el que use PHP DOM pero no logro conseguirlo:

```
$htmlEncoded = mb_convert_encoding($body1, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$opcionesLibXML = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
@$doc->loadHTML($htmlEncoded, $opcionesLibXML);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $scriptstag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
    foreach ($scriptstag as $scripts) {
        $src= $scripts->getAttribute('class');
        $posgif = strpos($src, 'twitter-video');
        if ($posgif === false){
        }else{
            $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
            $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
            $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
            $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
            $scripts->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $scriptstag);
        }
    }                           
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
?>
```

La salida me lo regresa asi:

```
<div class="media_embed">
    <figure class="op-interactive">
        <iframe>
        </iframe>
    </figure>
    <script async="" charset="utf-8" height="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" width=""></script>
</div>
```

Me podrian ayudar porfavor
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas reemplazando el `blockquote` (`eg: $scripts->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $scriptstag);`), en lugar de agregarlo al `iframe`.

### Solución:

- Puedes utilizar [`parentNode`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) para hacer referencia al `DOMElement` padre del `blockquote` y desde este llamar a [`insertBefore`](http://php.net/manual/es/domnode.insertbefore.php) para agregar el `figure` exactamente antes del `blockquote`.
- Puedes utilizar [`appendChild`]  sobre `$iframeNuevo` para añador el `blockquote` dentro de este.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$htmlEncoded = mb_convert_encoding($body1, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$opcionesLibXML = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
@$doc->loadHTML($htmlEncoded, $opcionesLibXML);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$scriptstag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('blockquote');

foreach ($scriptstag as $scripts) {
    $src= $scripts->getAttribute('class');
    if (strpos($src, 'twitter-video') === false) {
        continue;
    }
    
    $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
    
    $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
    
    // Agregamos el `figure` antes del `blockquote`
    $scripts->parentNode->insertBefore($figureNuevo, $scripts);

    // Agregamos el `blockquote` dentro del `iframe`
    $iframeNuevo->appendChild($scripts);
}                           
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad60276b13f5967572524be6699f98ed2adac82d)</kbd>

Comment: muchas gracias funciono muy bien, y gracias por la explicacion saludos